# SQL syntax error, while using java(eclipse)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse

i'm using java eclipse as well as mySQL workbench to able to connect with each other.  Now i'm using java to code some queries, but having a specific problem with a query question with an error i'm not familiar with and my first encounter after making a couple of sql query that works fine. Any help is appreciated.  I will list the code, then follow up with an error.

```
public static void stopTimes() throws SQLException
    {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Enter Route Number: ");
    String route = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Direction?");
    String dir = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the first stop number:");
    String stop1 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the second stop number:");
String stop2 = scan.nextLine();      
String sql;

  sql = "SELECT DISTINCT bus_stops.stopID, street1, street2 FROM bus_stops INNER JOIN scheduled_stops ON bus_stops.stopID = scheduled_stops.stopID"+
              "WHERE scheduled_stops.routeNumber = '"+route+"' "+
              "AND scheduled_stops.direction = '"+dir+"' "+
              "AND scheduled_stops.stopTime > (SELECT stopTime FROM scheduled_stops WHERE scheduled_stops.stopID = '"+stop1+"' ORDER BY scheduled_stops.stopTime asc limit 1)"+ 
              "AND scheduled_stops.stopTime < (SELECT stopTime FROM scheduled_stops WHERE scheduled_stops.stopID = '"+stop2+"' ORDER BY scheduled_stops.stopTime asc limit 1)";


      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         String stopID  = rs.getString("stopID");
         String street1 = rs.getString("street1");
         String street2 = rs.getString("street2");
         String stopTime = rs.getString("stopTime");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("Stop ID: " + stopID);
         System.out.print(", Name: " + street1 + "/" +street2);
         System.out.println(", Time: " + stopTime);
      }

}

java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'
scheduled_stops.routeNumber = '051' AND scheduled_stops.direction = 'Northbound''
at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1695)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3020)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2949)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:959)
at TransitManager.stopsOnRoute(TransitManager.java:460)
at TransitManager.main(TransitManager.java:104)
```

Comment: the problem is in th sql query you are making , try to tested with phpmyadmin or mysql workbench before you add it to java code

Comment: add white-spaces at the end of each line of your query.

Comment: ok thanks for the comments.  I'll be more careful with spaces along with testing mySQL workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While generating query keep one thing in mind that to run first it in sql shell or tool then implement in your code with proper spacing and string manipulation.

```
 sql = "SELECT DISTINCT bus_stops.stopID, street1, street2 FROM bus_stops INNER JOIN scheduled_stops ON bus_stops.stopID = scheduled_stops.stopID"+
                  " WHERE scheduled_stops.routeNumber = '"+route+"' "+
                  " AND scheduled_stops.direction = '"+dir+"' "+
                  " AND scheduled_stops.stopTime > (SELECT stopTime FROM scheduled_stops WHERE scheduled_stops.stopID = '"+stop1+"' ORDER BY scheduled_stops.stopTime asc limit 1)"+ 
                  " AND scheduled_stops.stopTime < (SELECT stopTime FROM scheduled_stops WHERE scheduled_stops.stopID = '"+stop2+"' ORDER BY scheduled_stops.stopTime asc limit 1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sql`-String for missing spaces at the end of the first and fourth row.

Comment: Appreciated, i'll be careful with spaces

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space between `stopID` and `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks for comment, will indeed becareful with spacing

Answer (score 0):

Use Whitspaces properly. Try this:

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT bus_stops.stopID, street1, street2 FROM bus_stops INNER JOIN scheduled_stops ON bus_stops.stopID = scheduled_stops.stopID "+
              "WHERE scheduled_stops.routeNumber = '"+route+"' "+
              "AND scheduled_stops.direction = '"+dir+"' "+
              "AND scheduled_stops.stopTime > (SELECT stopTime FROM scheduled_stops WHERE scheduled_stops.stopID = '"+stop1+"' ORDER BY scheduled_stops.stopTime asc limit 1) "+ 
              "AND scheduled_stops.stopTime < (SELECT stopTime FROM scheduled_stops WHERE scheduled_stops.stopID = '"+stop2+"' ORDER BY scheduled_stops.stopTime asc limit 1)";
```